# Hide a list when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, hide, show

I have a `share` link that shows a list of links when clicked. I'm using `toggle` to hide and show this list.

When the list is visible, the user can click `share` to hide (toggle) the visibility of the list of links.

However, the small problem with this is, the list of links remain visible until the user toggles the list by pressing `share`.

I added this script to make it possible to close the list if the user clicks outside the list.

```
$(".meta-share").click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".social-share").fadeToggle();
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {

  var container = $(".social-share");

  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {

    container.fadeOut();

  }
});
```

However, the `toggle` doesn't work as expected now.

Can anyone help?

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StephenMeehan80/vtdpdpkL/) showing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because you say to fade when you click on the target and next to the target. all you have to do is return false when the target is meta--share in your document.mouseup.

```
$(".meta--share").click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();

  $(this.nextElementSibling).fadeToggle();
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {

 if(e.target.className == "meta--share"){
    return false;
 }
 var container = $(".social-share");

 if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {

   container.fadeOut();

 }
});
```

here's your adjusted fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9hpw15oq/2/

**Update**

in the .click function. instead of looking for the element through class. select the element using the .click event.

I have updated the code and fiddle

Comment: That's great, thank you so much. That's solved the first issue, the page will have 2 of these share links. One at the top and one at the bottom. How would you limit it to only open the one that's clicked? Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/StephenMeehan80/9hpw15oq/

Comment: It is better to use `e.target.classList.contains('meta--share')` , I think

Comment: well I would probably see if I can select the closest target, but I'm trying to think of a way to do that.. @noder how so?

Comment: Also if I were you I would start making click functions like so: `$('#targetId').on('click', function(){  //your code here  })`  this is more up to date if you're using the latest jquery version

Comment: I just updated my answer again cause I realised I could've also just used `$(this.nextElementSibling)` instead of `$(event.target.nextElementSibling)`

Comment: @FllnAngl brilliant, a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

This code should work fine :

```
$(".meta--share").click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  if($('.social-share').is(':visible')){
   $(".social-share").fadeOut();
  }
  else{
  $(".social-share").fadeToggle();
  }

});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {

  var container = $(".social-share");

  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {

    container.fadeOut();

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".meta--share").click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".social-share").toggle();
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {

  var container = $(".social-share");

  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {

    container.fadeOut();

  }
});
```

```css
.social-share {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="meta--share" href="#">Share</a>
    <ul class="social-share">
      <li class="facebook"><a title="Share on Facebook" href="#">Facebook</a></li>
      <li class="twitter"><a title="Share on Twitter" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
      <li class="linkedin"><a title="Share on Linked" href="#">Linkedin</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```